# R - broom::tidy for binomial GLM- Error in approx(sp$y, sp$x, xout = cutoff) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, r-mice

I'm trying to run a logistic regression model in R to identify auxiliary variables which predict missingness in other variables to run a multiple imputation by chained equations model.

Below, var_1 is the missingness variable, computed from another existing variable (0 = not missing, 1 = missing).

For the model, I'm using a logistic regression to predict missingness (0,1) from other variables, and those which are predictive at the p<0.05 level will be used as auxiliary variables which predict missingness.

I'm aware this is not the method normally used to identify auxiliary variables for MICE but this is what I have been advised to do and cannot deviate from this method.

```
var_1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
var_2 <- c(14, 13, 16, 12, 11, 16, 8, 13, 14, 16, 11, 15, 13, 15, 15, 7, 15, 14, 14, 7, 16, 14, 12, 16, 12, 16, 12, 12, 11, 13, 16, 12, 13, 13, 12, 14, 12, 16, 10, 14, 16, 14, 16, 16, 12, 8, 15, 14, 14, 14, 12, 15, 10, 12, 10, 13, 14, 16, 11, 7, 14, 9, 15, 14, 13, 9, 16)
var_3 <- c(13, 10, 16, 8, 10, 13, 8, 16, 13, 12, 4, 3,  8, 11, 13, 8, 8, 13, 10, 9, 16, 13, 1, 14, 12, 14, 12, 10, 12, 11, 16, 9, 9, 5, 7, 14, 15, 16, 10, 8, 16, 12, 12, 7, 13, 4, 16, 13, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
var_4 <- c(16, 16, 12, 16, 13, 17, 15, 19, 12, 18, 15, 19, 15, NA, 17, 11, 10, 13, NA, 11, 18, 18, 11, 12, 11, 19, 10, 15, 17, 17, NA, 17, 15, 15, 17, 18, 15, 14, 11, 13, 14, 15, 20, 16, 12, 11, 17, 16, 11, 15, 15, 15, 11, 11, 9, 13, NA, 12, 13, 14, 13, 15, 19, 15, 15, 15, 16)

df <- cbind(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4)

lm_1 <- glm(var_1 ~ var_2, data = df, family = binomial())
broom::tidy(lm_1, conf.int = TRUE)
lm_2 <- glm(var_1 ~ var_3, data = df, family = binomial())
broom::tidy(lm_2, conf.int = TRUE)
lm_3 <- glm(var_1 ~ var_4, data = df, family = binomial())
broom::tidy(lm_3, conf.int = TRUE)
```

All glm functions will compute, but for broom::tidy, lm_1 works, lm_2 doesn't, and lm_3 works (lm_3 was given as an example to show the model can handle some NA values).

I've figured out that this is most likely because var_1 has 0 values up until the 49th variable, and 1 from 49 onwards except for the 56th which is 0, whereas var_3 has na from the 50th onwards except for the 57th, which is 0. This means that the model cannot compute based on only 1 non-zero, non-NA value.

Is there an alternative model, method, package or function which I can utilise which will help me achieve my desired outcome? I can see that swapping the variables to 1 = not missing, 0 = missing will probably work - will this provide me with the correct result? I realise I'm probably overthinking this, I have been trying to deal with it a long time.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, I'd love any advice you might have!

Comment: `var_1` and `var_3` are perfectly correlated. Everywhere `var_1` is 1, `var_3` is NA. Since you can only fit rows where both values are not missing, your `var_1` values are a constant 0 so you can't really fit a statistical model to that. I'm confused because you say you have to use this particular method but then are asking for alternative methods. But no method will really help with a data problem like this. If you want statistical advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions which this does not seem to be.

Comment: Okay thank you @MrFlick, apologies for the confusion!

Comment: (1) I think you need `data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4)` rather than using `cbind()`; (2) You *might* be able to hack around this, but it would be challenging.